# Can't find location of dsmodel.mof - Dymola

Tags: dymola

I cant find the location of the generated dsmodel.mof file from my Translated and Simulated model.

Where can i see the save location of the file without searching through every folder on my computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be in your working directory. 
You can find (and change) the location of your working directory of it using either the GUI:
- File -> Working Directroy -> Browse
or by typing
`cd` into your command line in the Simulation view.
Adding a parameter to the `cd` command will change the location, like in `cd("C:/Temp/DymolaWD")` (the path has to exist before using `cd`)

Alternatively you can use the folder-like looking button in you command window in the simulation view to open it directly in the Windows Explorer, by clicking the small arrow next to it and selecting `Open in File Browser`.